# Find the most recent item inside the ANY that matches condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Have been trying to figure out this problem for somedays but did not come to a solution yet. This is my current query:

```sql
SELECT e.id, case when 7768 = any(e.class) then 'INP' else 'OUT' END AS type,
    cc.display   AS typedesc,  ccc.display, 
    cccc.display AS status3 ,  pat.id       AS patid, 
    pat.gender              ,  pat.birthdate,
    l.alias      AS room_ref,  l.name       AS room_name,
    l.id         AS room_id ,  ll.id        AS bed_id,
    ll.alias     AS bed_name,  l.partof,
    concat(hn.prefix,' ',hn.given,' ',hn.family), e.plannedenddate
FROM ecosystem.encounter e
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept cc   ON cc.id   = any(e.class)
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept ccc  ON ccc.id  = e.priority
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept cccc ON cccc.id = e.subjectstatus
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.patient pat ON pat.id = (e.subject->>'identifier')::int
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.practitioner prac 
  ON prac.id = (SELECT (zz->'actor'->>'identifier')::int 
                FROM jsonb_array_elements(e.participant) zz 
                WHERE zz->'type'->>'code' = 'ATND')
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.humanname hn ON hn.id = any(prac.name)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ecosystem.locations WHERE form = 7930) l 
  ON l.id = (e.location[jsonb_array_length(e.location)-1]->>'identifier')::int
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ecosystem.locations WHERE form = 7931) ll 
  ON ll.id = (e.location[jsonb_array_length(e.location)-1]->>'identifier')::int
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(e.participant) AS papi
  WHERE jsonb_typeof(papi->'actor') = 'object' 
    AND (papi->'actor'->>'identifier') = '27'
    AND (papi->'actor'->>'reference') LIKE 'Organization/%')
AND e.status in ('in-progress','on-hold','discharged')
AND 3 = any(l.partof)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(participant) pa
  WHERE pa->'type'->>'code' = 'ATND' 
    AND pa->'actor'->>'identifier' ='99')
```

This is my attenmpt from my old query to query where the patients are inside the hospital. Before we only did need the room, and therefore this:

```sql
left join (select * from ecosystem.locations where form = 7930) l 
on l.id = (e.location[jsonb_array_length(e.location)-1]->>'identifier')::int
```

was valid since the last element inside e.location was the room of the patient. Now that is not the case since it can be a room or a bed, and somehow I would need to filter the `any` and match the latest item that matches any of the `id`s of the subquery on the left side.

Comment: Ca you provide `create table` and some mock/sample `insert` statements to demonstrate current vs desired behaviour? A dbfiddle.uk link would be very handy.

Comment: Can you trim the noise from this query monster to focus on the core question? Show some sample values, the desired result, and disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below, I introduced a `LATERAL` join to dynamically handle the situation where the last element in the `e.location JSONB` array can either be a room or a bed. This join first identifies the latest location from `e.location` and then conditionally connects to the locations table based on whether the location is identified as a room `(form 7930)` or a bed `(form 7931)`.

```
SELECT e.id, 
       CASE
           WHEN 7768 = ANY(e.class) THEN 'INP' 
           ELSE 'OUT' 
       END AS type,
       cc.display as typedesc,
       ccc.display, 
       cccc.display as status3, 
       pat.id as patid, 
       pat.gender, 
       pat.birthdate,
       l.alias  as room_ref,
       l.name as room_name,
       l.id as room_id,
       ll.id as bed_id,
       ll.alias as bed_name,
       l.partof,
       CONCAT(hn.prefix,' ',hn.given,' ',hn.family), 
       e.plannedenddate
FROM ecosystem.encounter e
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept cc on cc.id = ANY(e.class)
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept ccc on ccc.id = e.priority
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.codeableconcept cccc on cccc.id = e.subjectstatus
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.patient pat on pat.id = (e.subject->>'identifier')::int
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.practitioner prac on prac.id = (SELECT (zz->'actor'->>'identifier')::int FROM jsonb_array_elements(e.participant) zz WHERE zz->'type'->>'code' = 'ATND')
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.humanname hn on hn.id = ANY(prac.name)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ecosystem.locations 
    WHERE id = (e.location[jsonb_array_length(e.location)-1]->>'identifier')::int 
      AND form IN (7930, 7931)
) loc ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.locations l ON loc.id = l.id AND l.form = 7930
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.locations ll ON loc.id = ll.id AND ll.form = 7931
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(e.participant) AS papi
    WHERE
        jsonb_typeof(papi->'actor') = 'object' 
        AND (papi->'actor'->>'identifier') = '27'
        AND (papi->'actor'->>'reference') LIKE 'Organization/%'
)
AND e.status IN ('in-progress','on-hold','discharged')
AND 3 = ANY(l.partof)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(participant) pa
    WHERE pa->'type'->>'code' = 'ATND' 
      AND pa->'actor'->>'identifier' ='99'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I try this approach before, the problem is that this gets either only the room, either only the bed, and we need both.

Comment: You can adjust the join conditions or the structure of the LATERAL join to accommodate cases where both types of locations are present in the e.location array, to make it work the wat you want it

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering using a subquery .This will help you filter for the latest matching location .The subquery is as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM ecosystem.locations l
    WHERE l.id = ANY (
        SELECT e.location[i]->>'identifier'::int
        FROM generate_subscripts(e.location, 1) g(i)
        ORDER BY i DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AND l.form IN (7930, 7931)
) AS l ON TRUE
```